# What is $\frac{\partial x^TA^{-1}y}{\partial A}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, partial-derivative

I had trouble proving the following:

> If $ A\in \mathbb R^{n\times n}$ and $A$ is nonsingular, $x \in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$,  $y \in \mathbb R^{n\times 1}$, then $ \dfrac{\partial x^TA^{-1}y}{\partial A} = -A^{-T}xy^TA^{-T}$, (in which $A^{-T} = (A^{-1})^T$

The "Matrix Cookbook" simply mentions that the above formula could be derived from the basic identity $ \dfrac{\partial Y^{-1}}{\partial x} = -Y^{-1}\dfrac{\partial Y}{\partial x}Y^{-1}$. But how exactly does it work?

I'm stuck on this problem for quite a while. Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, there's actually a step in between in the [Matrix Cookbook](http://www.math.uwaterloo.ca/~hwolkowi/matrixcookbook.pdf), which makes this a lot clearer:

$$
\frac{\partial\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{kl}}{\partial X_{ij}}=-\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{ki}\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{jl}
$$

This you can get from the relationship that you quoted by setting $x=X_{ij}$:

\begin{align}
&\frac{\partial\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{kl}}{\partial X_{ij}}\\
=&-\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial X_{ij}}\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{kl}\\
=&-\sum_{\rho.\sigma}\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{k\rho}\left(\frac{\partial\mathbf X}{\partial X_{ij}}\right)_{\rho\sigma}\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{\sigma l}\\
=&-\sum_{\rho.\sigma}\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{k\rho}\delta_{i\rho}\delta_{j\sigma}\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{\sigma l}\\
=&-\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{ki}\left(\mathbf X^{-1}\right)_{jl}\;.
\end{align}

Now the relationship that you want can be derived like this:

\begin{align}
\frac{\partial x^\top A^{-1}y}{\partial A_{ij}}
&=x^\top\frac{\partial A^{-1}}{\partial A_{ij}}y\\
&=\sum_{k,l}\left(x^\top\right)_k\frac{\partial\left(A^{-1}\right)_{kl}}{\partial A_{ij}}y_l\\
&=-\sum_{k,l}\left(x^\top\right)_k\left(A^{-1}\right)_{ki}\left(A^{-1}\right)_{jl}y_l\\
&=-\left(A^{-\top}x\right)_i\left(A^{-1}y\right)_j\;,
\end{align}

so

$$
\frac{\partial x^\top A^{-1}y}{\partial A}=-A^{-\top}xy^\top A^{-\top}\;.
$$

Comment: The explanation is very clear. Thanks a lot!