# Gradient of the identity plus inverse w.r.t to the matrix, with constant entries

Tags: linear-algebra, partial-derivative, symmetric-matrices

I am trying to compute the gradient of the quadratic form $f(L):=s^T (I+L)^{-1}s$ w.r.t to $L$, i.e.

$\frac{\partial s^T (I+L)^{-1}s}{\partial L}$,

where the variable $L$ is a PSD symmetric matrix with some entries that are constant and equal to zero (let's say we have a set $\mathcal{A}=\{(i, j) | L_{ij}=0\}$).

Now, if all entries of $L$ are variables then the gradient is (see [What is $\frac{\partial x^TA^{-1}y}{\partial A}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1381573/what-is-frac-partial-xta-1y-partial-a))

$(I+L)^{-1}ss^T(I+L)^{-1}$.

How can I derive a formula for the gradient that takes into account the fact that some entries are constant (and equal to zero) and therefore their differential is 0?

Comment: In short: you can simply set the entries $[\frac{\partial f}{\partial L}]_{i,j}$ for $(i,j) \in \mathcal A$ equal to zero. In general, you can get the gradient of a function over a linear subspace by projecting the overall gradient of the function onto that subspace

Comment: Thank you very much. 
I came to the same conclusion by deriving the gradient entry by entry. Nevertheless, comparing my gradient descent implementation and the one of CVXpy, I get different results if $|\mathcal{A}|\neq 0$. The projection that you mentioned (setting 0 to the entries in $\mathcal{A}$), is the "best" that I can get?

Comment: I believe so. That said, it might be the case that cvxpy is doing some kind of [conjugate gradient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conjugate_gradient_method) based method